# How can TCP and UDP ports have the same port number?

Tags: sockets, networking

How is this possible? Any explanation for this, that two TCP and UDP ports can have the same port number?

Comment: Any explanation for you thinking they can't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both TCP and UDP use IP packets to transmit data. An IP packet contains a protocol number (6 for TCP, 17 for UDP) that allows the protocol stack to distinguish between TCP and UDP packets appearing on the same port. A more complete list of possible protocols that might be carried by IP can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers)